# How to get the next and previous row value in repeater item command?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Is there any way to get the next or previous row value of repeater on Item_Command event of repeater?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this... in your Item_Command handler:

```
Button senderButton = (Button)sender;
RepeaterItem currentRepeaterItem = (RepeaterItem)(senderButton.NamingContainer);
int currentRepeaterItemIndex = currentRepeaterItem.ItemIndex;

RepeaterItem previousRepeaterItem = MyRepeater.Items[currentRepeaterItemIndex-1];
RepeaterItem nextRepeaterItem = MyRepeater.Items[currentRepeaterItemIndex+1];
```

Comment: As an aside, make sure to check for first and last items when performing the `+1` and `-1`